# Creating join multiple associations using GraphQL & Relay

Tags: ruby, graphql, relay, graphql-ruby

I am using GraphQL Ruby and making it compatible with Relay. I am trying to find the **correct** way of creating records in a join table using Relays node IDs. I know I can take an array of node IDs and get look up each object using `Schema.object_from_id`, but that would cause an N+1 query and I am trying to avoid that.

Is that the only way to do it if I use Relay node IDs? What is the best practice for this situation?

Data model for reference:

We have `Photo`s, `Gallery`s, and the join model is `GalleryPhoto`. I have the ids for the photos and want to create a new gallery.